Custom, Sequence-Based ID Generator spring boot 3.2.3
I am trying to implement custom sequence generator. ( like all the primary key of table are prefixed with bill_
I am using
spring boot 3.2.3
hibernate 6.4.4.Final 

tried the approach mentioned in https://thorben-janssen.com/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/
but getting the below error
2024-04-25T15:25:47.189+05:30  INFO 26510 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-04-25T15:25:47.193+05:30  INFO 26510 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-04-25T15:25:47.195+05:30  INFO 26510 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-04-25T15:25:47.203+05:30  INFO 26510 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-25T15:25:47.210+05:30 ERROR 26510 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Receiver class io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.array.internal.StringArrayTypeDescriptor does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.hibernate.type.BasicType resolveType(org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration, org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect, org.hibernate.type.BasicType, org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ColumnTypeInformation, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcTypeIndicators)' of interface org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BasicPluralJavaType.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.dpw.warehouse.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.array.internal.StringArrayTypeDescriptor does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.hibernate.type.BasicType resolveType(org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration, org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect, org.hibernate.type.BasicType, org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ColumnTypeInformation, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcTypeIndicators)' of interface org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BasicPluralJavaType.
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiKeyLoadHelper.resolveArrayJdbcMapping(MultiKeyLoadHelper.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiIdEntityLoaderArrayParam.<init>(MultiIdEntityLoaderArrayParam.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.buildMultiIdLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.prepareLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3420) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Incompatible libraries. Use the proper HIbernate version for use with the Highpersistence utils.

hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60 is compatible with hibernate version we are using. ( 6.4 )

according to GitHub it isn't and  you should use the 63 version. That it isn't compatible is also pretty clear from the error you get.

tried by adding the below dependency

io.hypersistence
hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63
3.7.4

still getting the same error.

You should replace the dependency not add it. Add your pom.xml to the question.

https://gist.github.com/saipavanbhanu/a08a30cfd564da2cbfeb200e02f4d6e1

As I stated replace the dependency you still have the old dependency in there (the com.vladmichaela one. Ditch that. Also your pom also shows very hard work to work around the dependency management that spring is doing for you.

i commented out the earlier dependency. and added the new dependency in the pom.xml as you can see.
I am looking to go for the sequencing via db approach using trigger, function & sequence.
I will add more info if i am successful via db approach.

Again you still have an even older dependency in there, the com.vladmicheala one which predates the one you are using now. Remove it. And you are messing with dependencies managed by Spring Boot so you get a mixture of possible incompatible versions. Not sure why you are trying to outsmart the existing dependency management.

i didn't understood. You want me to remove hibernate core & validator dependencies from pom ? because spring manages internally ?
updated the gist as well.

i have updated the gist. and now i am able to run the application.  Need to check if i am not breaking any existing apis.
Thanks a ton Deinum :)

@M.Deinum - i have updated the pom.xml in the above gist. can you help me what could be the issue and how to resolve it ?

You were able to run the application, so not sure what you did to break that again. Seems like a different question don't abuse this one again.

I was able to run the app. but after checking i came to know that most of the src files are not included. that is why i am able to run the application.
even if i raise the new question, the details will be same.

No it won't, one thing is that everything is in dependencyManagement not in dependencies. Also ditch spring.version and remove the version tag for the spring-boot-starter-* dependencies. Most of the issues you get are from trying to outsmart the dependency management that is done by Spring Boot.
